# xmlhttpRequest error on google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a method in javascript that does the folowing:

> ```
>  var X =  new XMLHttpRequest();
>  X.open('GET',U,false);
>  X.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','text/html');
>  X.send('');
> ```
>
> where U = path to a file...example: xyz/abc.txt.

It works fine on firefox, but opening it on chrome gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
```

It says error on X.send('').I tried

```
X.send(null); //did not work
X.send()     // did not work.
```

Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I get this error in chrome when I try and use `XMLHttpRequest` within a file launched my local hard drive. The script works file when run from a web server. I assume this is a security feature.

How are you launching the file containing the script above?